# Visual Studio keeps telling me that xcode isnt installed

Tags: c#, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

So I recently setup my Mac and I tried using the xamarin agent to connect to it after installing xcode and going through the agreement thing. It connects.. Kinda and then it says that xcode isnt installed.

Here is a gif showing what happends
https://gfycat.com/DisguisedMarvelousGoldenretriever

What is causing this issue? Because I have xcode installed on my mac

Comment: have you tried launching XCode?  It often prompts you to accept a EULA and possibly install additional tools

Comment: @Jason Yeah I started it and created a project, still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You must change Xcode path from tools menu. for do that go to **Tools** > **Option** > **Xamarin** select **iOS Settings** and change Xcode path.

You can also check **Use Defualt Xcode path** option and change your Xcode path to Application folder in Finder, if you cannot find the Xcode app in Application move it to Application Folder.